# Why isn't Scapy capturing the whole HTML code?

Tags: html, scapy

I have made a Scapy script that will ask the user what website they wish to extract HTML code from (must be HTTP for obvious reasons), and then set up the 3 way TCP handshake with the website. Once this have been done, the code will send a GET request and store the reply to that GET request to a variable and print the HTML code portion of the received packet.

However, whenever I run the code, only a small portion of the overall HTML code for the website is saved/captured.

```
`from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.http import *
from scapy.layers.inet import *

# Asking user what website to get HTML from
website = input("Website (e.g www.example.com): ")

# 3 Way Handshake

# Creating SYN Packet
synPacket = IP(dst=website) / TCP(dport=80, flags='S')

# Capturing SYN-ACK Packet
synAckPacket = sr1(synPacket)

# Creating ACK Packet
ackNum = synAckPacket.seq + 1
seqNum = synAckPacket.ack
port = synAckPacket.dport
ackPacket = IP(dst=website) / TCP(sport=port, dport=80, flags='A', seq=seqNum, ack=ackNum)

# Sending ACK Packet
send(ackPacket)

# Creating GET Packet
getPacket = IP(dst=website) / TCP(sport=port, dport=80, flags='PA', seq=seqNum, ack=ackNum) / HTTP() / HTTPRequest(Host=website)
send(getPacket)

# Capturing GET Reply Packet
replyPacket = sr1(getPacket)
print(replyPacket[Raw].load)
`
```

I am testing this with [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

I receive:
'<!doctype html>\n\n\n    Example Domain\n\n    \n    \n    <meta name="v'

Instead of the whole HTML code for the website.

In Wireshark it shows the packet I am receiving and the one in Wireshark contains all of the HTML code.

I expect to see the whole HTML code for that website as shown below.

[Whole HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y32x7.png)

I have tried different ways of searching for the HTTP GET response however, I am pretty sure I have captured the correct packet as in Wireshark the packet that I am capturing contains the WHOLE HTML code.